LG LSC27926SB refrigerator freezer door water line broken

I think I tried every single youtube video to replace this tube but nothing matches with my exact model. Can someone please share instructions on how to replace this tube that connects to left of this blue connector in the picture and goes inside the freezer door. Water leaks from bottom when I press the water dispense button in the freezer side door. Model number: LSC27926SB

I think that you have to replace the door ... I have the same problem and have not found a solution that does not involve cutting holes in the interior side of the door

If you really can’t make the junction work (John Guest union connectors are common), maybe try an uninterrupted run from inside the door to the main connection in the body of the unit.
